# Statistical analysis in R of three groups with categorical variables

Tags: r, chi-squared

New to using R, and I am trying to assess a group of patients over three time points. There are 21 patients who have a categorical variable (a score of 1 through 6). The three time points are arranged in columns.

So effectively there is a 21x3 table (21 observations of a categorical variable (score of 1 through 6) at each timepoint.

I want to compare to see if there is significant improvement in score over the three time points. I was using Chi-square analysis but want to see if there are more appropriate testing options in R to assess this problem.

Comment: For your data, wouldn't it be more appropriate to consider the score (1 through 6) as a quantitative variable (as opposed to categorical), and then do a comparison along the lines of "does the average score increase over time"?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Chi-square is incorrect method of analysis for longitudinal data. Try a mixed effects model or GEE approach.

Comment: The Friedman Test may also be appropriate here (see `fried.test()`). But I agree that your question is more appropriate for Cross Validated.